# How to place a text box directly below legend in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using `matplotlib`, I'd like to place a text box below the legend, containing some notes about the figure. My legend is outside the axes to the right. My plan was to find the legend's position in the figure's frame of reference, then use the `text` method of the figure to place my notes. However, I can't *figure* out how to get those legend coordinates. Any suggestions or alternative plans would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently one can only read the legend's position once its rendered. The coordinates will be in pixels. So, it is possible to create a new axis using `fig.add_axes` that will be just below the legend using the legend's coordinates and the figure's dimensions. Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
fig,ax = subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
ax.plot([0,1],'.-',label="line1")
ax.plot([0.1,1.1],'.-',label="line2")
leg = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),loc=2, borderaxespad=0)

fig.canvas.draw() # this draws the figure
                  # which allows reading final coordinates in pixels
leg_pxls = leg.get_window_extent()
ax_pxls = ax.get_window_extent()
fig_pxls = fig.get_window_extent()

# Converting back to figure normalized coordinates to create new axis:
pad = 0.025
ax2 = fig.add_axes([leg_pxls.x0/fig_pxls.width,
                    ax_pxls.y0/fig_pxls.height,
                    leg_pxls.width/fig_pxls.width,
                    (leg_pxls.y0-ax_pxls.y0)/fig_pxls.height-pad])

# eliminating all the tick marks:
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off',
                bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off',
                labelright='off', labelbottom='off')

# adding some text:
ax2.text(0.1,0.1,"some text\nabout the\nlines")
```

Which generates this figure:

[image]

The frame can be turn off easily if not needed.