# Using annotate to place a text box below legend in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I wish to display some text in a Matplotlib plot using annotate(), aligned beneath a legend box. I have examined the solution proposed in [How to place a text box directly below legend in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299383/how-to-place-a-text-box-directly-below-legend-in-matplotlib/49314045#49314045) and can make an adaption that works for my situation, however adding additional axes etc. seems overkill for my situation. I simply wish to place an annotation whose top right corner is 20 pixels below the lower right corner of the legend box.
I also wish to save a PDF files of the plot.

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([5,1], label="Label 1")
ax.plot([3,0], label="Label 2")

legend = ax.legend(loc="upper right")

# Create offset from lower right corner of legend box,
# (1.0,0) is the coordinates of the offset point in the legend coordinate system
offset = matplotlib.text.OffsetFrom(legend, (1.0, 0.0))
# Create annotation. Top right corner located -20 pixels below the offset point 
# (lower right corner of legend).
ax.annotate("info_string", xy=(0,0),size=14,
            xycoords='figure fraction', xytext=(0,-20), textcoords=offset, 
            horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')
# Draw the canvas for offset to take effect
fig.canvas.draw()

fig.savefig('plot1.png')
fig.savefig('plot1.pdf')

plt.show()
```

When the plot is first shown it looks correct, with the information text correctly beneath the legend. Also, the saved png file shows correctly. However, the text is missing in the pdf output.

I am not sure if there are gaps in my understanding, or if something is wrong. Can anyone shed some light why the pdf output is incorrect?

png output

[image]

pdf output

[image]

(matplotlib=2.2, python=2.7.13, Windows 7)

Comment: I have since tried this using matplotlib version 2.2. This version generates the *.png files correctly, but the *.pdf are still incorrect.

Comment: Though this is a relevant question, I encourage you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not inviting for potential helpers to see a cluttered code containing lots of things that have nothing to do with the question. Reduce your code to a reproducible example and people will be more eager to help you out.

Comment: I edited your question to be more clearly asking about the actual problem.

Comment: thanks for your comments MrT and IOBE.
IOBE - When I first encountered this problem, I was simply generating two PDF files, one showing the full axes and the other zoomed in on a particular region of interest. The first PDF would be correct, but the second incorrect. I suspected the change in xlim/ylim combined with the coordinate offset may have been a contributing factor. Thanks for narrowing this further.

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem with the PDF rendering/backend rather than what the original title suggests....

Comment: This is likely a bug in matplotlib. You should open an issue on github.

Comment: Cross reference: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10844

Comment: My knee jerk reaction is a missing dpi conversion / unit confusion and the text is being placed at 20 inches for the bottom of the legend.

Comment: tacaswell - If you increase the length of the annotation text (eg. 'extra_information_string') the first few characters become visible in the extreme top right hand corner of the figure.

Comment: great solution thanks !